# 2D line passes through two points, vector parallel to line?

Tags: vectors

Suppose a 2D line passes through two points P0(10, 15) and P1(200, 20) what are the point to the vector parallel to the line?

I attempted this |P0P1|/|P1P0|= answer but what I got does not appear to be correct.

Also how do I find the vector perpendicular to the line?

How do I find the equation to represent the line?

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but a vector from $P_0(x_0, y_0)$ to $P_1(x_1, y_1)$ can be written $(x_1-x_0, y_1-y_0)$.

A vector perpendicular to that can then be written as $(y_1-y_0, x_0-x_1)$, or as $(y_0-y_1, x_1-x_0)$.  (The two are opposites of each other.)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!